# Console session logging on problems

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm currently working in a company where many of us log onto hosts/servers via windows console session.
If one person is logged on and another tries it causes the person who was logged on first (and maybe doing something important) to be cut off.

Is there such a thing as an application for such events where before logging on people can see if any other IP address is controlling the host/server, 
Also if the person on the console session had the ability to leave a note for anybody thinking of taking over the session of when they are finished etc.. 
I have many other ideas for such things but could any of you guys tell me if the application exists??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off-topic for security.stackexchange.com - more suitable for ServerFault, I'd think.

Answer (score 1):

From your own machine, run the command: eventvwr \\server-name

This would allow you to see the events for the machine named server-name. Provided your account have proper access to see the event logs, you would be able to determine whether someone is currently logged in or not.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Open "Remote Desktop Services Manager" anywhere on the same domain (so you have the rights on the machine). It will show the sessions for the machine your are at by default.

1. Right click on the "Remote Desktop Services Manager" node
2. Select "Connect to computer"
3. Select "Another computer" and enter the name or ip address

You will see a list of the current sessions :

[image]

Right click on a session for more information and the ability to send a message. A phone call or a short walk usually works better, though.

You can enforce a mandatory kill session, maybe something like:

- Disconnect idle session after 20 minutes
- Kill idle session after 30 minutes